# How to use subscript in java string?

Tags: java, string, subscript

How can I write subscript characters in a Java string?

For example, I have to write `"CO2"`. How can I move `2` to the bottom of `CO`?

Comment: Instead of the number two why not use the [UTF-8 subscript 2 symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2082/index.htm)?

Comment: Where will this string be displayed? A string is a series of characters and contains not information on formatting in itself.

Comment: "subscript" is not a Java concept.  The Java langauges and standard libraries deal with strings (sequences of characters).  The question of what sequence of characters should be rendered as a subscript in print or on a screen is answered at a higher level (e.g., google for "java rich text editor")

Comment: see StyleConstants (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyleConstants.html). There is a Subscript value you can use with styled documents

Answer (score 8):

The `String` class doesn't provide such operations. But you could use the [Unicode Character 'SUBSCRIPT TWO' (U+2082)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2082/index.htm):

```
final String string = "CO\u2082"; // CO₂
```

Also, you could create a `String` as an HTML snippet. For instance,

```
final String html = "CO<sub>2</sub>";
```

Comment: For the sake of maintainability I'd probably recommend that "\u2082" is made a constant with a sensible name; ie `private static final String SUBSCRIPT_TWO = "\u2082"` so that it is explicit what is being done when you look at the code 6 months later

Comment: @beresfordt, it's good notice, but... Why use a static class variable, if I use it only in one place?

Comment: Without having "\u2082" in some named variable it's likely you'll forget what it is. Having it as constant local variable in a method seems a bit off; it is a constant so I'd use the java-y way of declaring constants; `private/public/protected static final` - just a stylistic choice

Comment: Thanks dear, but both the options are not working. I am using jdk6

Comment: `System.out.println("CO\u2082");` prints `CO₂`

Comment: not as good as `System.out.println("CO" + SUBSCRIPT_TWO);` :p

Comment: package com.ax;
public class Demo {
 private static final String SUBSCRIPT_TWO = "\u2082";
 public static void main( String[] argv ) {
  //  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\
   //String SUBSCRIPT_TWO = "\u2082";
        //String subScript = "CO\u00BA";
       System.out.println("CO"+SUBSCRIPT_TWO);
    }

} OUTPUT:- CO?