# How to display subscript in java

Tags: java, string, console

I want to write a program to display on console a list of subscript H_i where i is in [0, N].
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414960/how-to-use-subscript-in-java-string) is an example to display the CO2 using the unicode. How to get the same expression if the index is greater strictly than 9?

Comment: Are you expecting us to write the solution for you? What have you tried so far? I guess you should create a method that breaks a number into its digits, converts every digit into its subscript and combines the subscripts into a string

Comment: What's wrong with using multiple subscript characters? e.g. Glucose: C\u2066H\u2081\u2082O\u2086

Answer (score 2):

try to use this method

```
public String generateSubscript(int i) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : String.valueOf(i).toCharArray()) {
        sb.append((char) ('\u2080' + (ch - '0')));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: You can replace the whole body of the for-loop by `sb.append((char) ('\u2080' + (ch - '0')));`